# Contents between tags to turn into title JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `<a class="wishlist">TEXT</a>`

i need `<a class="wishlist" title="TEXT"></a>`

I can use only JS.

Comment: Please specify your question more clearly. Your question itself is not even present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your selector is a class, I'd set the function up to handle the possibility of multiples.

```
$('.wishlist').each(function() {
    $(this).attr( 'title', $(this).text() ).empty();
});
```

Don't forget to either place this code after your HTML, or wrap it in document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

try it again:

```
$('.wishlist').attr('attr','TEXT').html("");
```

Comment: sorry, but this no working. i need remove from TEXT <a>TEXT</a> and add TEXT to title <a title="TEXT">

Answer (score 0):

`$('.wishlist').attr('title', $('.wishlist').text() );`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".wishlist").attr("title", $(".wishlist").text()).text("");
```

That will set the title attribute to the current text, and afterwards unset the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('wishlist').title = 'TEXT'
document.getElementsByClassName('wishlist').innerHTML = ''
```